# See previous inputs in Scrapy Shell?

Tags: terminal, scrapy, pycharm

So in the regular python terminal you can push the up arrow to see what you have previously entered into the terminal and I was wondering if there was an equivalent to this in the scrapy shell?

Edit
I am using the Pycharm Terminal if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Installing https://pypi.org/project/pyreadline/ solved that problem. Seems like is a problem with readline.

```
pip install pyreadline
```

Edit: Or you can just use PowerShell, go to your project directory then shift+right click, open PowerShell then `.\venv\Scripts\activate` to activate your venv and finally scrapy shell.